# Displaying a Message in a C# web application

Tags: c#

I have a switch statement in C# and I would like to have the default case display an error message when its implemented.  I cant use MessageBox because this is a web application but i dont know how to do this any other way.  I have been advised to use Javascript but Im not sure how to do this.  Im assuming I need to create a pop up box in the HTML and then implement the onclick event into the last case or something.  thank you for you time

```
case 8:
    function
    break;
case 9:
    function
    break;
default:
    //insert message here
    break;
```

Comment: MVC or ASP.Net? Is that C# code? Where are you doing this in the Page_Load? You need to give us something to work with here. Your question is very very vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
// The message you want to display.
string message = "your message";
// Here you will build a script using the StringBuilder object
// which will be executed, when the onload event of your page will be triggered.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
sb.Append("alert('");
sb.Append(message);
sb.Append("')};");
sb.Append("</script>");
// Here you register your client script 
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
```

which you will place it in your `default` option.